# Firefox bug with Selenium - Can't access dead object

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I've tried to run my tests with Selenium 2 and Firefox 19. One of this tests causes an error "ERROR: Command execution failure. The error message is: can't access dead object".

I'm reading about it, it seems like a bug in newest Firefox's versions. Lot of people have the same issue, but I've not found anything really clear.

Any heroe can help us? Maybe we just need to change something in "about:config"?

Regards

Comment: I doubt this is a bug, more likely that the ff engine evolves and selenium need some time to adapt. i had similar issues with selenium webdriver. i now use an "old" version of firefox for testing that I set up in a way that prevents it from auto-updating itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, luksch. Your answer would be good for me, but unfortunately, I need to run it with Firefox 18-19-20. Thanks anyway

Comment: i read up on this now. it seems that ff changed this by design already in ff 15. according to  https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/ it should be easy for an extension to adapt, but selenium did not follow it seems. can you move away from using the ff-extension and maybe use a webdriver based approach for testing?

Comment: What version of the IDE?

Comment: What kind of object is it trying to interact with, when it throws the _dead object_ error? Is the object disabled, or hidden, or made inaccessible by a div in front of it, or anything like that?

Comment: Selenium IDE is 2.0.0.

Comment: I Think it happens when the page is reloaded

Comment: Mozilla people answered me. There's nothing we can do, it just Selenium isn't adapted to this kind of versions. "Best" option is go back to previous Firefox versions.

Comment: This problem isn't with an extension - because I get it running the tests with PHPUnit, or htmlsuite - the problem is selenium itself, but nobody seems to want to listen

Answer (score 21):

I was desperate about the same Problem and didn't find any solution although many people seemed to have the same problem.

I solved it by calling

```
webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

before calling any findElement method
(using Java)

Comment: It worked for me. I was using Selenium 3.3.1 with Firefox 52.0.2 esr. Just writing "driver.switchTo().defaultContent();"  before my executeScript instruction and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me as well. I am using Selenium 3.4.0 with Firefox 54.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

This error generally comes when you do no switch back from frame and trying to access web elements directly.
Use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` and then try to access the elements

Answer (score 0):

I finally made a "cheat" to the browser.

I got the fail when Selenium clicked on a link and try to open the new page. What I've made is just simulate the click, doing a selenium.open("URL") which replace selenium.click("link=ButtonWhichOpenTheURL").

It seems to work by the moment

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error on Firefox 23 while reopening a pop up browser window. The only workaround I did is closing the current selenium session and relaunching it again. It worked fine for me.