# "Malformed URL: can't access dead object" in selenium when trying to open google

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

With python selenium I am currently developing a very complex test case. In the midst of it (page might be loading, with iframes inside iframes etc), I just want to open a webpage by doing as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

but I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: Malformed URL: can't access dead object
```

Can't I open just a webpage somewhere in my selenium tests? Why is this a malformed URL? What do dead objects have to do with navigating to a new webpage...?

Comment: This link may help you to resolve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396767/firefox-bug-with-selenium-cant-access-dead-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you switched into a frame just before .get(). And you cannot open an url in the frame. Try `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: Yes thats it. I really need to write a wrapper around selenium, so it becomes useable....

Answer (score 1):

Why do we see the error **`can't access dead object`**

Lets us assume we have a `Web Page` which contains an `iframe` which is inside another `iframe`. So the hierarchy is as follows :

```
page root (grandparent) -> iframe (parent) -> iframe (child)
```

Now, within the **`iframe (child)`** if we interect with an `WebElement` (example `click a button`) that destroys/closes the child, we may face the error **`can't access dead object`**.

### Reason :

It seems that the driver is trying to maintain a reference to the button that was clicked. However, the button no longer exists and thus the webdriver implodes.

### What could have went wrong :

In an attempt to improve memory usage and to prevent memory leaks Firefox disallows add-ons to keep strong references to DOM objects after their parent document has been destroyed. A dead object holding a strong reference to a DOM element that persists even after it was destroyed in the DOM is the root cause of this error.

As an example, the current implementation of GeckoDriver do not always check for a valid top-level browsing context. Which means in case of navigating away from a frame and trying to invoke **`get()`** method, which might close it, the following command may fail because the context is no longer available.

### Solution :

In these cases, the solution is to navigate back to the **`default_content`** or **`parent_frame`** and then try to invoke **`get()`** method as follows :

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")
//frame tasks
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

[**`Here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879) [**`are`**](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/594) [**`the`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Dead_object) [**`references`**](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/) [**`of`**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/614) [**`this`**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1349861) [**`Answer`**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1322383).

Comment: @Alex This answer should have given you some insights. Still, let to try to answer your current question with a better explaination