# Selenium IDE lose default content after unloading an iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe

I'm experiencing a very annoying bug with selenium IDE, firefox and html runner.
I'm testing a single page, with an inner iframe dinamically loaded after a click on a button.

I can see the iframe content by `selectFrame | id=frame1` and all is ok.
Then, i click a button on the frame and this cause the iframe to be unloaded.

After that, i can't access to anything in the main page, even if i do:

`selectWindow | title=`, the command is ok, that is the same as `SwitchTo().DefaultContent()`, but it seems all the content is no more here, every xpath lookup fails.

I tried assigning a button id to a variable BEFORE loading and unloading the iframe with `assignId | //button[2]`,

but when later i use the variable to access the button i get

> can't access dead object

It seems that unloading the inner iframe all the content in the outer window was lost, but the page is already there ( iput a `waitForElementPresent` to wait indefinitely and i see the page with all its stuff.

Any ideas ?

- Firefox 59
- Selenium IDE 2.9.1
- Selenium Gecko Driver 0.20
- Selenium html runner 3.10

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Malformed URL: can't access dead object" in selenium when trying to open google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770694/malformed-url-cant-access-dead-object-in-selenium-when-trying-to-open-google)