# Unable to switch out of nested frames into main page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I have a program that does automated data entry on the PLM platform, ENOVIA, with specific information that I input. I'm using Selenium to navigate the webpage. There is a segment where the program has to enter 4 nested frames to click a certain element. It does that well and makes the necessary edits, the problem I'm facing is when I try to exit out of the frames back to the top of the HTML code to get back to the main page using **switch_to.default_content()**. For some reason, after it switches into the 4th child of the nested frames and makes these edits, I see that the window changes to only consist of these frames and whats within them, and nothing above the 1st parent frame. So **switch_to.default_content()** doesn't seem work.

This is the code that really matters, where it switches into the 4th and final frame "DSCObjectSummary" and makes these edits

```py
def clickCheck(Method, Locator, elemName):
    #Add If Else to check for element availibility
    #Do Retries of searchess
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((Method, Locator)))
        print(elemName + ' Clickable')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Cannot Find Element")

...... Lots of code and comes to this point
    #Switching into 4 nested frames to click "EDIT DETAILS" Button
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("content"))
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("detailsDisplay"))
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("portalDisplay"))
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("DSCObjectSummary"))
    clickCheck(By.ID, 'DSCEditObjectSummary', "Edit Details")
    elemEdit = browser.find_element_by_id("DSCEditObjectSummary")
    elemEdit.click()

    #Click the Customer Dropdown
    clickCheck(By.ID, "PMCCustomerId", "Customer Dropdown")
    elemCust = browser.find_element_by_id("PMCCustomerId")
    elemCust.click()
    elemCust.send_keys("Ces")
    """Add If Conditions to check part number"""

    #Click Document Type Field
    clickCheck(By.ID, "PMCDocumentTypeId", "Document Type")
    elemDoc = browser.find_element_by_id("PMCDocumentTypeId")
    elemDoc.click()
    elemDoc.send_keys("MOD")

    """Add Check to see if part is Active/Obsol, if Obs, make Active"""

    #Click Dashnumber field
    clickCheck(By.ID, "PMCDashNumber", "Dash Number")
    elemDash = browser.find_element_by_id("PMCDashNumber")
    elemDash.click()
    elemDash.clear()
    elemDash.send_keys("-1")

    #Click Done Button
    clickCheck(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='btn-primary'][type='button']", "Done Button")
    elemDone = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='btn-primary'][type='button']")
    elemDone.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()
    time.sleep(20)
```

I have tried switching backwards from 4th to 1st parent frame using **switch_to.frame(framename)** in sequence then using **switch_to.default_content()** only to be thrown a NoSuchFrameException. All I want is to be able to get back out of the frames, just like I got into them, without changing/removing anything in the window and get back to the top level HTML.

Comment: Any reason why you feel _`switch_to.default_content()` doesn't seem work_? How are you concluding this?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `driver.switch_to.default_content()` you can also use:

```
browser.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

---

### Update

As you are still facing the same issue, a better approach would be to wait for the `elemDone.click()` step to be completed (*JavaScript* / *Ajax Calls*) and you can induce *WebDriverWait* for some `visibility_of_element_located()` as follows:

```
elemDone = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='btn-primary'][type='button']")
elemDone.click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_of_an_element_which_gets_displayed_after_the_click")))
browser.switch_to.default_content()
# as an alternative use `switch_to.parent_frame()`
# browser.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

**Note**: For debugging purpose you can replace the *WebDriverWait* with `time.sleep(5)`

---

### Outro

[“Malformed URL: can't access dead object” in selenium when trying to open google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770694/malformed-url-cant-access-dead-object-in-selenium-when-trying-to-open-google/47774529#47774529)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix my issue, it has the same results as default_content(). However, I have realized that the window only changes when I try to interact with the elements in the 4th nested frame using commands such as send_keys() or click(). Other than that, if I stop at only accessing the frame, I am able to exit out of them perfectly fine back into the top level using parent_frame() or default_content() and interact with other elements. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: @A.Gomes Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: This is further helping me narrow down the problem. According to your example of **page root (grandparent) -> iframe (parent) -> iframe (child)**, in my case, when I access iframe(childs) 's elements, the page root is removed, but the parent frame, and all its children exist. I can always reload the website and restart the edit sequence, but I refuse to believe there is no effective way to exit frames back into page root.

Answer (score 0):

try finding all iframes and switch to the one you  need.

```
// find all your iframes
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
        // print your number of frames
        System.out.println(iframes.size());

        // you can reach each frame on your site
        for (WebElement iframe : iframes) {

            // switch to every frame
            driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

            // now within the frame you can navigate like you are used to

        }
```

Comment: My problem is that the all other elements are removed as soon as I **interact** with the elements in my 4th nested frame. I can access it completely fine. How can I keep my page as it is while I edit elements within the frame?

Comment: @A.Gomes are you not able to find any iframes after edit elements within the frames

Comment: I think he is trying to switch out of the iframe to the main content.

Comment: The only iframes that exist are the 4 nested ones that I am inside, all other elements around these 4 frames do not exist.

Comment: @AppuMistri Yes, but the main content disappears after interacting with the iframe, and only those exist in the window. This is what I mean by the window changes. So i cannot exit out of the frames as there's nothing to go to, I'm just confused as to why the main content disappears only to leave the frames and its contents.

Comment: If there's no content there, why switch?

Comment: There was content before I accessed the frames, and after editing the elements within the frame, I am trying to exit back out into that content. But when I do these edits within the frame, the window changes to show only the frame and not the original content. I hope this is clear.

Comment: can you post the html source ? ( once after editing the elements within the frame)? I believe we can still traverse back to root element & switch to it. Also what happen if you save the edit or simply escape it?